# Utilizing a for loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, syntax

I hope you guys are doing well.

I have a quick question. Here is my code:

```
for(i in 2:49){
  PriceFun[i] = approxfun(data[i]$FUEL_PRICE_REAL ~ data[i]$dd)

  PriceFromDate[i] = function(x) {
    round(PriceFun[i](x), 3) }
}
```

What I want the output to be:

```
PriceFun2 = approxfun(data2$FUEL_PRICE_REAL ~ data2$dd)

PriceFromDate2 = function(x) {
  round(PriceFun2(x), 3) }

PriceFun3 = approxfun(data3$FUEL_PRICE_REAL ~ data3$dd)

PriceFromDate3 = function(x) {
  round(PriceFun3(x), 3) }
```

and so on...

Is my syntax incorrect? I rarely use R

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  As written, it's not clear what you're asking.  If you can show some sample data, it would help us understand whether you're trying to loop through a list of data.frames (which would be `data[[i]]` if `data` is your list) or what.

Comment: I thought my question was pretty clear. There is an issue with the syntax, not with parsing. I simply confused how to use a for loop in R with my example.

Comment: please show us `str(data)` or nobody will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

1) Would you give more information on the data type of "data" and "PriceFun"? If those are lists, did you make empty lists in front of for loop?

2) I think the body of the function inside the loop would give you the syntax error. If you want to call the elements of the list, try using square bracket [], instead of ().

3) You can round the whole column by just using round(PriceFun[i], 3).

Comment: PriceFun looks interpolates data that looks something like this:
`data1
       [date]    [fuel price] 
[1,]  01/15/2010     3.56           
[2,]  01/17/2010     3.32          
[3,]  03/18/2010     3.45           
[4,]  04/20/2010     3.94        
[4,]  04/25/2010     3.94      `

It isn't a list. I simply want to make new variables with the for loop.